# How canonical is Gauss's law of composition of forms

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Gauss defined the composition of binary quadratic forms $f$ and $g$ to be another binary quadratic form $F$ such that there exist integral quadratic forms

$$ \begin{align} r(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1) &= p_0 x_0y_0 + p_1 x_0y_1 + p_2 x_1y_0 + p_3 x_1y_1\\ 
s(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1) &= q_0 x_0y_0 + q_1 x_0y_1 + q_2 x_1y_0 + q_3 x_1y_1 \end{align}$$

for which

$$  F(r(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1),s(x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1)) = f(x_0,y_0)g(x_1,y_1) $$

(and satisfying one extra technical condition).

In Section 236 of Gauss's *Disquitiones Mathematicae*, he shows how to find a form which is composed of two other forms.  After laying out the notation, he begins by saying that you can take ad libitum four integers satisfying a pretty minor condition (minor enough that there are usually infinitely many ways to select these integers).  He then constructs a composition of two forms, which depends on how you choose the four integers.

In Section 242, he moves to considering the composition of two binary quadratic forms of the same discriminant.  At that point, he says that we can take the four integers to be $-1$, $0$, $0$, and $0$ and does so seemingly for the remainder of the work.  With this choice, we get the composition operation on forms (and not just on ideal classes) that is common in other works.  Namely, the first coefficient of the composition is a divisor of the product of the first coefficients of the forms to be composed, and the middle coefficient of the composition is obtained by solving a certain system of congruences.  (A special case of this is Dirichlet's definition of composition.)

By choosing the four integers differently, you can produce other forms that are compositions of two given forms.  For instance, the following identities are readily checked:

$$ (5x_0^2 + 7x_0y_0 + y_0^2)(5x_1^2 + 7x_1y_1 + y_1^2) = 
\begin{cases}
5r_0^2 + 13r_0s_0 + 7s_0^2, \\
7r_1^2 + 15r_1s_1 + 7s_1^2, \end{cases}$$

with

$$ \begin{align} r_0&=x_0y_0-2x_0y_1-2x_1y_0-3x_1y_1, & s_0 &=x_0y_0+3x_0y_1+3x_1y_0+4x_1y_1\\
r_1&=3x_0y_0 - x_0y_1 - x_1y_0 - 2x_1y_1, & s_1&=-x_0y_0+2x_0y_1+2x_1y_0+3x_1y_1\end{align}$$

Thus, we see both $5x^2 + 13xy + 7y^2$ and $7x^2 + 13xy + 7y^2$ exhibited as compositions of the form $5x^2 + 7xy + y^2$ with itself.

When Gauss turns to defining the class group for a given discriminant beginning in Section 242, he seems to make a rather arbitrary choice of which form to use as the composition of two given forms of the same discriminant.  My question is:  is there anything canonical about Gauss's definition (other than -1, 0, 0, and 0 being nice, simple numbers)?  His operation turns the classes of primitive forms under the action of the matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & c\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ into a group.  But could the compositions have been systematically chosen in a different way to produce a group?

Or if it is not canonical, are there several functions from the ideals in a quadratic field to the corresponding binary quadratic forms through which multiplication of ideals translates into different operations on forms?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Gaussian composition is between classes of quadratic forms.  $5x^2+13xy+7y^2$ and $7x^2+15xy+7y^2$ are properly equivalent and thus in the same class, so they represent the *same element* of the group of classes of quadratic forms of discriminant 29. (They represent $-1, 1, 5, 7$; they can both be reduced to $x^2+7xy+5y^2$.)

Comment: The *modern* view of composition is that it is an operation on classes. Gauss's definition was much more general, composing individual forms and even composing forms of different discriminants. That's why I say "when Gauss turns to defining the class group... he seems to make a rather arbitrary choice of which form to use..." The whole premise of the question is about the choices he makes when he moves from the composition of forms themselves to the composition of their classes.

Answer (score 2):

The composition of binary quadratic forms that has always been used is a version developed by Dirichlet. This can be found on page 49 in the first edition of [Cox](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118390180.html#), with a correction in the second edition.

It is quite recent that [Bhargava](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v159-n1-p03.pdf) showed that there were actually 14 distinct ways to, say, implement the conditions described by Gauss. Bhargava got a Fields Medal for the job.

[image]

Comment: Dirichlet's definition seems to me a special case of the composition Gauss defines in Section 242.  With the choice of the four integers -1, 0, 0, 0 that I mentioned, the gcd of a, a', and (b+b')/2 is what Gauss calls $\mu$ (Dirichlet assumes $\mu=1$). Gauss's definition of composition in Section 242 says that the composition of $(a,b,c)$ and $(a', b', c')$ is $(\frac{a a'}{\mu^2}, B, C)$, where in Section 243, he proves that $B$ is determined by congruences that essentially look like those in Cox (but different because of Gauss's convention on the middle coefficient).

Comment: So I wonder why this definition is attributed to Dirichlet.  In any case, Gauss's more general definition still uses that choice of -1, 0, 0, 0 which is not unique.  That's the non-canonical part I'm interested in .  Is there a reference for the 14 implementations of Bhargava?  I didn't find "14" in a search through the first composition laws paper.

Comment: https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/icm2014-bhargava-laudatio/

Comment: Oh, okay, so those are for other types of quadratic forms (higher degree or more variables).  But it sounds like his cubes might make Gauss's choice canonical.  I'll think about it more.  Thanks.

Comment: @BarrySmith You may have a good point about Bhargava's composition laws applying to homogeneous forms of higher degree, leaving just the known method for binary forms. The Dirichlet method had a fair amount of start-up work to get the two forms into shape where the formula from Cox can be used. It is not obvious that this can be done, or how, and that was written down by Dirichlet somewhere. He called such a pair "united." More detail is in Cox or, my favorite, Buell.

Comment: @BarrySmith I knew the number 14 because Bhargava told me when visiting MSRI in the 1990's, mostly to see Kaplansky. I thought he meant 14 ways for binary forms, it did seem that way. However, this is all down on paper now, and popular accounts published as well, there are avenues to find out for sure.